# Inclusion-Exclusion proof for two sets

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

I know this might sound silly but, it's easy to convince myself that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ but i'm not sure how i would go about proving it.

Suppose $A'=A\setminus\{a\}$ and $|A|=n+1$ for some positive integer $n$ then $\begin{align}
|A\cup B|&=|A'\cup B|+|\{a\}|\\
& =|A'|+|B|-|A'\cap B|+ |\{a\}|\\
& =|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|
\end{align}$

So is this correct??

Comment: It might be easier to just write $$A\cup B = A\sqcup (B\setminus(A\cap B)) $$where the RHS is a disjoint union.

Comment: Your proof assumes $a \notin B$. So you also have to treat the case $a \in B$ (which is done using the fact that we have $A \cup B = A' \cup B$ and $A \cap B = (A' \cap B) \cup \{a\}$ in that case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A and B are disjoint then it's straight forward that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$.
Now, $|A\cup B|=|A\cup(A\cap B)\cup(A^{c}\cap B)|=|A\cup (A^{c}\cap B)|=\\ =|A|+|A^{c}\cap B|=|A|+|B\setminus (A\cap B)|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$

The third equality is due to the fact that $A$ and $A^{c}\cap B$ are disjoint sets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that induction here is the right method..

**Hint:** Rather prove that $|A\cap B|+|A\cup B|\ =\ |A|+|B|$ by counting the members on both sides of this equation. (Some members will be counted twice, but on both sides, which ones?)

Comment: Why can't induction do??

Comment: Because the statement is more general than to apply it only for *finite sets*, and mathematical induction (in its original form) is applicable only for the finite.

Comment: @Berci : speaking of the cardinality of a set (as a number) implies the set is finite here.

Comment: I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation would be correct if and only if $a\in A$ but $a\not\in B$.