# Set Theory Proof, revolving around the number of elements in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am learning about Set Theory currently. However, my teacher neglected to explain a concept that has shown up on one of the assigned proofs in the homework. The concept I'm struggling with is doing a proof with representation of the numbers in an element A for example. The proof is:

If $A$ is a set, then let $n(A)$ represent the number of elements in a finite set $A$
Prove that:
$$n(A\cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cap B).$$

I understand how to prove a regular set theory proof: such as maybe prove that $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.
You just need to use the definitions of intersection, union, etc. to convert these set statements into their logically equivalent counterparts. I just don't understand what is meant by the proof above. Thank you for your help. It's appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about finite sets? Also, it might help to use LaTeX, see at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about finite sets

Answer (score 1):

Take a point in $A\cup B$ and check that how many times it is counted if we calculate it by the formula $n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)−n(A\cap B)$ see that each point is counted exactly once, hence it gives a proof that the formula is correct!

Comment: You may find cases useful: An element of $A \cup B$ belongs either strictly to $A$, strictly to $B$, or to both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, you can "prove" this statement using Venn diagrams. When you add the cardinality of $B$ to the cardinality of $A$, you are adding twice the cardinality of $A\cap B$. So, we need to remove that counting subtrating it.

To give a formal proof to the statement $$n(A\cup B)=n(A)+n(B)−n(A\cap B)$$
you  need to know the definition of cardinality and bijection.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619617/inclusion-exclusion-proof-for-two-sets). Basically, we show that $$n(A\cup B)=n(A\cup (B\setminus A)).$$
Since $A$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint, we have $$n(A\cup(B\setminus A))=n(A)+n(B\setminus A).$$
Finally, we show
$$n(B\setminus A)=n(B)-n(A\cap B).$$

Answer (score 0):

The identity can be derived starting from only one basic assumption:  if $X$, $Y$ are disjoint i.e. $X \cap Y = \emptyset$, then $n(X \cup Y)=n(X)+n(Y)\,$.

A direct consequence is that if $Y \subseteq X$ is a subset of $X\,$, then $n(X \setminus Y) = n(X)-n(Y)\,$, which follows from applying the former to the union of disjoint sets $X = (X \setminus Y) \cup Y$.

> I understand how to prove a regular set theory proof: such as maybe prove that $\dots$

Then you may find it easier to follow if you start with the identity:

$$
A \cup B \;=\; \left(A \setminus B\right) \;\cup\; (A \cap B) \;\cup\; \left(B \setminus A\right)
$$

The three sets on the RHS are mutually disjoint, therefore:

$$
n\left(A \cup B\right) \;=\; n\left(A \setminus B\right) \;+\; n(A \cap B) \;+\; n\left(B\setminus A\right) $$

But $\,A \setminus B = A \setminus (A \cap B)$ where $A \cap B \subseteq A\,$ so $n(A\setminus B) = n(A) - n(A \cap B)\,$, therefore:

$$
\begin{align}
n\left(A \cup B\right) \;&=\; \big( n(A) - n(A \cap B)\big) \;+\; n(A \cap B) \;+\; \big( n(B) - n(A \cap B)\big) \\[3px]
&=\;n(A)+n(B)-n(A \cap B)
\end{align}
$$